# Only copy values of visible rows from one workbook into a new workbook using VBA Macros

Tags: vba, excel

I have some macros that copy Sheet 2 from my exsisting work book to a new work book. This code works as it should except that there are hidden rows that should not be shown on the new work book.

Here is the code that I have written that copies the sheet over and pastes only its values:

```
Dim Output As Workbook
Dim FileName As String

Set Output = Workbooks.Add
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sourceSheetName).Cells. _
    SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote Questions").Range("AK545").Value & ".xls"
Output.SaveAs FileName
```

So where would the code go that will only display the unhidden cells and not the hidden ones?

**EDIT**
The code has changed slightly after an answer was submitted. Here is more info.
Some of cells in the sheet that is being copied are merged and I get an error on the line of code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sourceSheetName).Cells. _
SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

Saying: `Cannot change part of a merged cell`, so im guessing there needs to another piece to add?

I do not want to go to the sheet and have un-merge all the cells manually.

Comment: They should not be copied because I don't want any link to the new workbook. I only want the values.

Comment: Ok thanks, will do that tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the line

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote & Proposal").Cells.Copy
```

with

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote & Proposal").Cells. _
    SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

and it should work.

Comment: I don't think you can only copy the visible part of any merged cell, where a part is hidden - this also causes an error when trying it in the UI without VBA. :-( You need to unmerge them at some stage. If you want to leave the original, I suggest you copy all columns - and then delete all hidden columns instead!

Answer (score 1):

#### Copy only visible Rows (not hidden)

You can check if the Row is hidden with this code

```
Sub RowIsHidden()
    For i = 1 To 7
        MsgBox Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden
    Next

End Sub
```

#### Copy Cells and Paste only Values

This is similar to your code above. Instead of index of the sheet you could also use the sheetname

```
Sub CopyOnlyValuesFromSheet()        
    ' Copy all Cells from first Sheet (SheetIndex =1)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy
    ' Select second Sheet (SheetIndex =2)        
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Select
    ' Paste only values into Selection 
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
End Sub
```

#### Clear Values of hidden Rows

I have tried to use `Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp` but since this has consequence over which rownumber i you have to iterate next it is easier to just clear the values

```
Sub RowIsHiddenClearValue()
    For i = 1 To 10
        If Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden Then                        
            Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Value = ""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

#### Based of Peters answer

Make sure that the cursor in the destination sheet is placed in the first cell.

```
Sub AnotherAnswer()
    Call CopyValuesOfVisibleRows("Quote & Proposal", "Quote Questions")
End Sub


Sub CopyValuesOfVisibleRows(sourceSheetName, destinationSheetName)    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sourceSheetName).Cells. _
        SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy        
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(destinationSheetName).Paste
End Sub
```

If you need more pointers to put the pieces together please provide more details with which parts you have problems.