# How do I implement the VBA module to copy filtered data

Tags: vba, excel

I need to implement a VBA Macro that copies data from one excel worksheet and puts certain column into another one.

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()

'Method 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B10").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E1")

'Method 2
'Copy the data
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B10").Copy
'Activate the destination worksheet
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
'Select the target range
Range("E1").Select
'Paste in the target destination
ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

This wont work for new sheets named for example Sheet 3 neither will it run effectively for filtered data. I need a code that can copy the filtered data and paste certain column into another worksheet.

Comment: see this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122063/only-copy-values-of-visible-rows-from-one-workbook-into-a-new-workbook-using-vba)

Comment: You need to copy the *visible* range in the actual range.

Answer (score 0):

This simplest way is *copyas* commend from oryginal file "with code" and delete this, what you do not want to share.

Another one relies on building string with code lines using *VBComponents* 
There you can check the code: http://vbatools.pl/tworzenie-linii-kodu-makrem-z-dodatku/

After that you file should to save as xlsm ora xls (old school) to save makros.